# What is the difference between `pip install package` and `python -m pip install package`?

Tags: python, pyspark, pip

This morning I had some problems with `pyspark` dependencies. Basically, I saw `Module not found error: pandas`. However, when I run python and do `import pandas as pd`, everything is fine - so obviously, `pandas` is appropriately installed.

What actually helped, is something described in this thread[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277201/no-module-named-pandas-error-occurs-when-using-pyspark-pandas-udf-with-aws). The solution was to use the `python -m pip install package` rather than the `pip install package`.

I'm trying to understand, what is the difference. Like, isn't behaviour supposed to be the same?

Comment: They do the same thing. In fact, the docs for distributing Python modules suggest using ```python -m pip``` instead of the ```pip``` executable, because it's easier to tell which version of python is going to be used to actually run pip that way.

Comment: so its basically shown here in the docs: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages and users are advise to do this: `py -m pip install "SomeProject"`

Answer (score 2):

To my mind the difference is this...

If you run:

```
python -m pip install ...
```

you are guaranteed to be running and installing to the same Python instance as you use when you run:

```
python SomeScript.py
```

---

If, on the the other hand, you run `pip` that might install to a Python2 interpreter or some other Python interpreter version you aren't using when you run Python scripts.

For example, you may have a `pip` that came with your Python 2.7 that installs modules for Python 2.7. You may also have a Python3, that you aliased to `python` like this:

```
alias python=python3
```

so you don't have to type `python3` all the time.

So, now you have `python` and `pip` that look like they work together hand-in-hand, but they don't because your `pip` installs for 2.7 but your `python` runs Python 3.

---

If you run:

```
pip -V
```

it will tell you which Python it works with.

If you run:

```
type python
```

it will tell you *where* the Python interpreter is that will get run.

If you run:

```
python -V
```

it will tell you the version of your Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer specifically because I keep forgetting and it is listed on the https://pypi.org website.

There is a link with the explanation is here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#use-pip-for-installing

And in particular the suggestion is this:

```
py -m pip install "SomeProject"
```

When users go to the package manager, the copy/paste option always omits the `py -m` component which **can cause problems if a user has multiple python versions**. Effectively installing the package to one of the other versions.

As Mark suggested, the `py -m` is important for ensuring that `pip` installs to the correct (current) version of python.